# EC2 start and stop automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have EC2 instance in Production where we run CICD.
Now we only use this EC2 when we have production deployment.And production deployment will be there hardly once in a month.But this production deployment time is not fixed.

So to save cost we want to run this EC2 only when we want to deploy.
We dont want to start and stop this EC2 manually using console.

What will be the best way to automate the start/stop of EC2 on adhoc basic ?
Note: There is not predefined time here when we want to run EC2.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal "on demand" approach would be using AWS CodePipeline services to organize CI/CD process. This way resources will be provisioned only when you need them, and process will triggered automatically.

Other than that, if usage pattern is unpredictable, the easiest way IMO would be to trigger instance waking up during CI/CD triggering stage, either with SDK or AWS CLI.

Comment: AWS CodePiple is not authorize service in my shop.Using AWS SDK if i write python boto3 code how i will invoke when required ?

Comment: That entirely depends on how you trigger build process. From the top of my head, I would launch instance, use `aws ec2 wait instance-running` until instance is up, and then proceed with build. Then stop instance as a last step of successful build.

Comment: But where to run `aws ec2 wait instance-running` as there is no instance running? Build process will start when there is commit in master branch.

Comment: Well, that is your issue. If your CI/CD pipeline is hosted on single instance, it's not going to cut it, you need some middleware to wake it up for you, like API gateway web-hook connected to lambda function. That's why I recommended CodePipeline. It's hard to tell you how to organize this without knowing your setup.

Comment: I can use API Gateway and Lambada function but how i can use them to start/stop EC2.I know i can write bto3 code to start/stop EC2 but how to determine when to invoke it?

Comment: Your VCS likely has webhook functionality. So when you push to master, webhook sends request to API gateway and lambda gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I use [ec2remote](https://github.com/jotaelesalinas/ec2remote). Disclaimer: I am the author of this repo.

Using these cli scripts, you can cron -or trigger however you want- something like:

```
./ec2control.sh -i <instance id> -s && \
  sleep 5 && \
  ./ec2ssh.sh -i <instance id> <remote cicd command> && \
  ./ec2control.sh -i <instance id> -d -f
```